# Multiple Activities in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to test 2 Activities in my project where when I click on a button in my first Activity, it should take me to the second Activity. Here I have given a click event to my button but when I run the project, I'm unable to see anything, its just a blank screen. What am I missing ?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onAddCLick(View view) {
        Intent TaskIntent = new Intent(this,SecondScreen.class);

        startActivity(TaskIntent);
    }
}
```

This is the second activity :-

```
public class SecondScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

        Intent task = getIntent();
    }

    public void cancl_btn(View view) {
        Intent goBack = getIntent();
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml :-

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="left"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="516dp"
        android:id="@+id/theListView">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/add_task"
        android:onClick="onAddCLick"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/setloc"
        android:onClick="onMapbtnClck"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"
        android:onClick="onSetngClck"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is second_layout.xml :-

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="left">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="364dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_name_edit_txt"
    android:text="Enter your Details here" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Location"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Set_loc_btn"
    android:onClick="set_usr_loc"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Add_task_btn"
        android:onClick="add_usr_tsk_btn"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel_btn"
        android:onClick="cancl_btn"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `activity_main.xml` is your layout file for your first activity, have you added a button to it?

Comment: Post your layout files

Comment: Do you have anything in your `R.layout.second_layout` and if so does it render in the graphical view of AS?

Comment: yes i have added a listview and a button in my first activity(activity_main.xml) and edittext and 2 buttons in my second activity

Comment: m not able to c nythng in my gui its just a blank white screen

Comment: Then you are going to have a blank screen. You probably need to post that xml. If it doesn't render there then it's not likely to render when you run the app (obviously depending on certain attributes).

Comment: have posted xml files..

Comment: @freddieptf have posted the files..plzz reply

Comment: You seem to be missing some of your second layout

Comment: ya thts definition for linearlayout.. lemme just edit n post the entire code

Comment: First, set your listview's height to wrap_content since it's empty and second, i'd recommend using normal buttons first to test if its a render issue or something is completely wrong with your layout

Comment: @freddieptf i modified as u said n i got it solved but m unable to c the listview.. is it coz of listview is empty ? n wht was the problem with imagebutton ?

Comment: Well the listView is empty so you wont see it, and i don't think the imageButton really had any problem. Pretty sure if you used them now they would be visible. What i think the issue was is the listView's height which pushed the buttons offscreen

Comment: yess u r right verified it by adding imagebutton n it is goin perfectly 5n.. got it solved.. thnk u so much was trying since 2 days..

Comment: @freddieptf setting `ListView` to `wrap_content` is not recommended. It should either be `match_parent` or  a fixed height/width

Comment: i want listview to b displayed whther ders sum data on it or not.. and all 3 buttons at the bottom of the listview whch shld cover the screensize.. how can i do tht ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

In first activity:

```
public void onAddCLick(View view) {
   Intent TaskIntent = new 
   Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondScreen.class); 
   startActivity(TaskIntent);
}
```

In second Activity:

```
   public void cancl_btn(View view) {
      Intent goBack =new 
      Intent(SecondScreen.this,MainActivity.class);   
      startActivity(goBack);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

by assuming that you have posted the complete XML file of the second layout,, I tried running it on my android studio and as you can see in the xml file itself  you are missing lot of information in it,,,

1. you need to define the schema as you have done in the first xml and
2. the < EditText > tag cannot be outside a container, you need to place it inside the container, that is, inside any kind of layout (linear, relative etc)..

if the issue is with the xml file then modifying it as per above two points will solve your problem,, hope this helps

Comment: Those are fair points but check the comments. It wasn't all posted. Also, it wouldn't have compiled if this were the issue.

Comment: yes I agree I posted the answer before you had actually updated the content of question,,, anyway I have your code and am trying to make modifications to make it run,, let me get back if I find something..

Comment: Actually when I run the code I am able to see two buttons ,, since the list view is empty the two buttons are appearing on top of screen ,,

Comment: yess me too modified n the listview isnt getting displayed but there r three bbuttons n button clck is goin to the second activity.. but wht shld i do of the listview ?

Comment: so is it coz the listview is empty it is not geting displyed ?